If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then the left and right limits equal $f(x_0)$
The Claim below comes from Analysis I, Terence Tao, third edition and is left unproven in the text. I found many proofs showing the converse. The ones that show the claim below use an epsilon-delta argument, which I want to avoid. Based on the below propositions and definition, I tried to work out a proof below, but I'm not sure if it's correct.
Claim. Let $x_0$ be an adherent point of both $X \cap (x_0, \infty)$ and $X \cap (-\infty, x_0)$. If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then $f(x_0 +)$ and $f(x_0 -)$ both exist and are equal to $f(x_0)$.
Proposition 9.3.9. Let $E \subseteq X \subseteq \mathbf{R}$, let $f : X \to \mathbf{R}$ be a function, let $x_0$ be an adherent point of $E$, and $L \in \mathbf{R}$. Then $f$ converges to $L$ at $x_0$ in $E$ if and only if for every sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ which consists entirely of elements of $E$ and converges to $x_0$, the sequence $(f(a_n))_{n=0}^\infty$ converges to $L$.
Proposition 9.4.7. Let $X \subseteq \mathbf{R}$, let $f : X \to \mathbf{R}$ be a function, and let $x_0 \in X$. Then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if for every sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ which consists entirely of elements of $X$ and converges to $x_0$, the sequence $(f(a_n))_{n=0}^\infty$ converges to $f(x_0)$.
Definition 9.5.1 (Left and right limits). Let Let $X \subseteq \mathbf{R}$, let $f : X \to \mathbf{R}$ be a function, and let $x_0 \in \mathbf{R}$. If $x_0$ is an adherent point of $X \cap (x_0, \infty)$, then we difine the right limit $f(x_0 +)$ of $f$ ar $x_0$ by the formula
$$
f(x_0 +) := \lim_{x \to x_0; \ x \in X \cap (x_0, \infty)} f(x)
$$
We define the left limit in a similar manner.

My attempt at proving the claim:
Assume the hypothesis. Let $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ consist entirely of elements of $X \cap (x_0, \infty)$ (and hence, of $X$) such that it converges to $x_0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, 9.4.7 implies $(f(a_n))_{n=0}^\infty$ converges to $f(x_0)$. This implies, by 9.3.9, $f$ converges to $f(x_0)$ at $x_0$ in $X \cap (x_0, \infty)$. That is,
$$
\lim_{x \to x_0; \ x \in X \cap (x_0, \infty)} f(x) = f(x_0)
$$
But the left-hand side is $f(x+)$ by 9.5.1. Thus, the above shows existence of $f(x_0+)$ and that $f(x_0+) = f(x_0)$.
A similar argument can be made for $f(x_0-)$.

Why do you avoid the $\epsilon-\delta$ language? In fact it is the most common way to define limit and continuity.

@Asigan I don't avoid it all the time -- but in this case, I think the notion of sequence convergence is more intuitive. If I were to use an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof, then $f$ being continuous at $x_0$ means that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in X$ satisfying $\left | x - x_0 \right | < \delta$, we have $\left | f(x) - f(x_0) \right | < \varepsilon$. Now I have to somehow use this to show that we have the same thing for when $x \in X \cap (x_0, \infty)$, but it isn't clear to me how that would be done.

Hint: If $x$ satisfies "$x\in X\cap(x_0,+\infty)$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta$", the it certainly satifies "$x\in X$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta$".

Personally, I find the sequence concept to hide the real point behind this theorem, rather than being more intuitive. Since $f$ is continuous, the two-sided limit exists. $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = L$ if for every neighborhood $V$ of $L$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $f(U\setminus{x_0}) \subseteq V$. The only difference between the various limits is how you define "neighborhood". The claim is true because every 2-sided neighborhood of $x_0$ is both a left and right neighborhood of it. And the union of any left and any right neighborhood of $x_0$ is a 2-sided neighborhood.

@PaulSinclair I see what you’re saying — I’ll keep this in mind and write up a proof in this regard.

@Asigan I posted an answer.

Per the comments, I decided to write an alternative proof using the epsilon-delta method.
Since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, we have that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in X$ satisfying $\left | x - x_0 \right| < \delta$, we have $\left | f(x) - f(x_0) \right| < \varepsilon$.
But we have that $X = (X \cap (- \infty, x_0)) \cup (X \cap (x_0, \infty))$. By the above paragraph, this implies that if $x \in X \cap (- \infty, x_0)$, there is a $\delta > 0$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\left | x - x_0 \right| < \delta$ implies $\left | f(x) - f(x_0) \right| < \varepsilon$. We have the same if $x \in X \cap (x_0, \infty)$. By definition of convergence/continuity and 9.5.1, we must have
$$
f(x_0 +) =\lim_{x \to x_0; \ x \in X \cap (x_0, \infty)} f(x) = f(x_0)
$$
and
$$
f(x_0 -) =\lim_{x \to x_0; \ x \in X \cap (- \infty, x_0)} f(x) = f(x_0)
$$

This is a nice proof! Now can you prove the other side, using Sinclar's hint? (More precisely, Sinclar's hint is that $$(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\setminus{x_0}\subseteq (x_0-\delta_1,x_0)\cup (x_0,x_0+\delta_2)  $$ where $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$. )

@Asigan I've already seen the proof of the other side; my main concern was proving the above :)
